# how to handle checkbox action in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have to call POST TYPE node Js API Function on button click but only when ever the user checks the checkbox. I am new to react-native.I am wondering how to handle checkbox action?

Answer (score 0):

you can use states to determinate whether or not the checkbox is checked:

On your constructor set the state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    checked: false
  };
}
```

Your checkbox:

```
<View>
   <CheckBox
      value={this.state.checked}
      onValueChange={() => 
        this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked})
      }
   />
</View>
<View>
  <Button title="Validate" onPress={this.validateHandler} />
</View>
```

Now your handler where if the checkbox pass he validation you can call your API method:

```
validateHandler = () => {
   if (this.state.checked) {
     console.log("validated"); //call the api
   }else{
     console.log("not checked"); //return and show a message or something
   }    
};
```